# Как посмотреть данные ответа oAuth

Tags: php, oauth

Использую oAuth 1.0a.

```
$consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer('key', 'secret');
$r_token = $consumer->getRequestToken('http://example.com/oauth/request_token'
, 'oob', array(), "GET");
'token' и 'token_secret' получаем следующим образом:
$_SESSION['token']        = $consumer->getToken();
$_SESSION['token_secret'] = $consumer->getTokenSecret();
```

'token' и 'token_secret' приходят. Но в ответе должен передаваться еще некий url как $r_token['login_url']

```
var_dump ($r_token['login_url']);
```

не работает.
Как посмотреть все данные которые пришли и как извлечь $r_token['login_url']?

Comment: `var_dump($r_token); var_dump($consumer);`

Comment: $r_token['login_url'] это protected value. Как мне извлечь его из объекта?

Comment: Найти метод, который возвращает это значение. Если такого метода нет, то можно воспользоваться рефлексией. Или же заинжектить данный метод в объект через `Closure::bind`